# Shell Script for checking existence of a directory

Tags: shell

```
if[-d /abmusr06/abm/users/dywrk01/run_time];
   then
     echo "Pack installation Failed"
     exit(1)
fi
```

This the above code fine?

Comment: With my maintenance hat on, your indentation seems a bit haphazard.

Answer (score 3):

Assuming this is Bourne Shell (/bin/sh):

```
if [ -d /abmusr06/abm/users/dywrk01/run_time ]
then
    echo "Pack installation Failed"
    exit 1
fi
```

- Put spaces around the brackets: `if [ -d`.  Think of `[` as a (key)word - it needs to stand by itself.  You wouldn't say `ls-l`, you say `ls`(space)`-l`.
- Use `exit 1`, not `exit(1)`.
- The semicolons are unnecessary if everything is on separate lines.
- The above seems to work in Cygwin for me.

Comment: Think of `[` not as a keyword, but as a command (because that's what it is)

Answer (score 0):

```
if [ -d "directory" ];then
 ....
fi
```